# $n \equiv 5$ (mod $6$) has a prime factor $p$ of $n$ such that $p \equiv 5$ (mod $6$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \equiv 5$ (mod $6$). Then there must be a prime factor $p$ of $n$ such that $p \equiv 5$ (mod $6$).

Let $n \equiv 5$ (mod $6$) such that $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_m^{a_m}$ where $p_i$'s are distinct primes. Any prime is either congruent to $1$ or $5$ modulo $6$, so if all $p_i$ are congruent to $1$ (mod $6$), i.e. $p_i=6k_i+1$, for some $k_i$ in $\mathbb{N}$, then $n=(6k_1+1)^{a_1}\cdots(6k_m+1)^{a_m}$. But then $n\equiv 1$ (mod $6$) because the constant factor in this product will always be $1$.

Is this proof correct? Did I miss any details?

Comment: You got the idea; there are primes congruent to $2$ and $3$ mod $6$, and you may wish to rule those out

Comment: Which ones exactly? $2$ and $3$?

Comment: Yes, those ones exactly

Answer (score 4):

Your proof is pretty good, though you missed that there are primes congruent to $2$ and $3$ mod $6$ (namely, $2$ and $3$), though we would not have $n\equiv5\pmod6$ if $2$ or $3$ divided $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct but is better phrased as proof of the contrapositive:

> If all prime factors of $n$ are congruent to $1$ mod $6$, then so is $n$.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I was just wondering if I missed any cases.

Comment: You do have to take care of when $n$ could have $2$ or $3$ as a prime factor. (This can be easily done because $5$ is coprime to both.)